# JDA setSendingHandler not defined for type Guild

Tags: java, discord

I am creating a bot for Discord using JDA (Java). I am facing a problem while trying to get my bot to play music in my voice channel.

The problem is in the following code

```
public static void startPlaying(net.dv8tion.jda.core.entities.Guild guild) {
    //Player player = getMyURLPlayer(guild.getJDA());
    FilePlayer player = getMyFilePlayer();

    //DiscordBot.bot.getAudioManager(guild).setSendingHandler(player);
    guild.setSendingHandler(player);
    System.out.println("Player.play is getting executed...");
    player.play();
}
```

In the above code, the following line is incorrect according to eclipse

```
guild.setSendingHandler(player);
```

It says that

```
The method setSendingHandler(FilePlayer) is undefined for the type Guild
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming that you are referencing http://jda.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/audio.html based on the code you've posted. The documentation on that site is beyond out of date. Not only is it incomplete and slightly incorrect, it is also for JDA 1.x. JDA is currently in 3.x and has undergone significant changes.

Additionally, FilePlayer (and URLPlayer) have been removed from JDA completely as they were incomplete and slightly buggy examples. For a proper implementation of an [`AudioSendHandler`](http://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/core/audio/AudioSendHandler.html) and player system, consider using [Lavaplayer](https://github.com/sedmelluq/lavaplayer).

Lavaplayer has an example directory for JDA [here](https://github.com/sedmelluq/lavaplayer/tree/master/demo-jda)

If you have any questions, feel free to join the [JDA Discord Guild](https://discord.gg/0hMr4ce0tIk3pSjp) and ask. There is also a channel especially for Lavaplayer support.